# How to proces xml using xmltable

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

I have an XML containing relation data such as this

```
<object name="object1">
   <attribute name="attribute1"/>
   <attribute name="attribute2">
      <value>value 1</value>
      <value>value 2</value>
   </attribute>
</object>   
<object name="object2">
   <attribute name="attribute1"/>
   <attribute name="attribute2">
      <value>value 1</value>
      <value>value 2</value>
   </attribute>
</object>
```

and I need to store this into the following relational model:

Table object

Table attribute FK to object

Table value FK to attribute

Using the XMLTable function I came up with the following solution:

```
declare

          -- This cursor retreives a record for each object with it's attribute values and 
      -- the underlying attributes as XMLtype
      cursor c_object(p_xml xmltype) is
             select obj.*
               from xmltable('$d//object' passing p_xml as "d" 
                              columns ... object columns ...
                             ,attributes xmltype path 'attribute') as obj;

      -- This cursor retreives a record for each attribute with it's attribute values and 
      -- the underlying values as XMLtype
      cursor c_attributes(p_xml xmltype) is
             select att.*
               from xmltable('$d//object' passing p_xml as "d" 
                              columns ... attribute columns ...
                             ,values xmltype path 'value') as att;

      -- This cursor retreives a record for each attribute with it's attribute values and 
      -- the underlying values as XMLtype
      cursor c_values(p_xml xmltype) is
             select val.*
               from xmltable('$d//object' passing p_xml as "d" 
                             ,columns value varcahr2(100) path 'value') as val;                      

    begin

       -- p_xml contains the XML document

       for r_obj in c_obj(p_xml) loop
          -- insert an object record
          insert into object...

          for r_att in c_att(r_obj.attributes) loop
             -- insert into attribute
             insert into attribute ...

             for r_val in c_val(r_att.values) loop
                -- insert into values

             end loop;
          end loop;
       end loop;
    end;
```

Is this the proper way to do this? Or how would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is so horribly incomplete, but I hope it leads in the right direction.

Your solution does a LOT of XML parsing. It may work, but if there is a lot of data to process I would imagine it would take a while. Indexing the XML would likely help, and may make your approach acceptable.

A better solution would probably be to use the `DBMS_XMLSAVE` or `DBMS_XMLSTORE` packages.